# MySQL ADDTIME doesn't know about switching to DST

Tags: mysql, dst

Got hit big time with the switch to Daylight Saving Time this year. I was assuming that ADDTIME was safe regarding DST cutoff times, but it isn't. My bad ... I should have checked.

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME('2015-03-29 01:55:32', '0 00:10:00') |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 2015-03-29 02:05:32                          |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

In my TZ, `2015-03-29 02:05:32` didn't exist: It ought to be `2015-03-29 03:05:32`!

The solution I came up with was to encapsulate the call to `ADDTIME` within `CONVERT_TZ`:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ(ADDTIME(CONVERT_TZ('2015-03-29 01:55:32','Europe/Paris','UTC'), '0 00:10:00'),'UTC','Europe/Paris') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-03-29 03:05:32                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Has anyone come up with a better (/safer) option ?

(Same problem with `SUBTIME`, `TIMEDIFF` and any functions that do math on time)

Regards,
Thierry

Comment: It's inconclusive whether you save data to MySQL or not. Basically, this issue is solved by saving all date/time related information into a `timestamp` column type. Once you pull the data, you use your user's TZ to display the correct time. Same rule applies for querying against `timestamp` column, coerce the user input into UTC date. Since your question is generally about the "algorithm" you came up with, I'm posting this as a comment, I've no idea if it'll help you or not.

Comment: Thanks NB. It's part of a `SELECT` statement. The objective is to provide some date-time information computed from a value read from the DB. I simplified the call for the sake of the example, showing up what happened around the moment of switch to DST.  (`ADDTIME(b.startT,  '0 03:50:00') AS 'STDFsetup4h',`)

Comment: Are you using a `datetime` type or `timestamp` for `b.startT`?

Comment: It's DATETIME ... but I've tested it, it doesn't make any difference. In both cases:  `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, `SELECT ADDTIME(startT, '0 00:10:00')` returns `2015-03-29 02:05:32` to `2015-03-29 01:55:32` plus 10 minutes ... as far as I've noticed ... unless I'm doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do math with local date/time values - exactly for the reason you discovered.  Also, you should probably be *storing* UTC values to begin with.  `TIMESTAMP` conversions only works if you're diligent about the session's time zone being set properly.  In many cases, you just want to store a UTC value in a `DATETIME` field and do the conversions in your application code.

Comment: Hello Matt, this exactly what I'm doing in the first place : All my dates/time are stored in UTC form. I'm gathering data coming from Europe, Africa, Asia. But still, I have to do math because I have to compute offsets from these data. I got lured into thinking that ADDTIME was "TZ aware", which it is not.

Comment: ... I gave only a succinct example for a "fix".  However, the actual math is much more complex and the TZ information about the origin of the data is also stored in DB along with the data. Behind that, this is a system that keep tracks of processed material that is handled in different countries of the world and were all results data must be centralized in one specific location.